# How to return value from async coroutine scope such as ViewModelScope to your UI?

Tags: android, kotlin, scope, viewmodel, coroutine

I'm trying to retrieve a single entry from the Database and successfully getting the value back in my View Model with the help of viewModelScope, but I want this value to be returned back to the calling function which resides in the fragment so it can be displayed on a TextView.

I tried to return the value the conventional way but it didn't work. So, How Can I return this value from viewModelScope.launch to the calling function?

**View Model**

```
fun findbyID(id: Int) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val returnedrepo = repo.delete(id)
        Log.e(TAG, returnedrepo.toString())
        // how to return value from here to Fragment
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
suspend fun findbyID(id: Int): userentity {
    val returneddao = Dao.findbyID(id)
    Log.e(TAG, returneddao.toString())
    return returneddao
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Thank you Nataraj KR for your Help!*

*Following is the code that worked for me.*

**View Model**

```
class ViewModel(application: Application):AndroidViewModel(application) {
val TAG = "ViewModel"
val repo: theRepository
val alldata:LiveData<List<userentity>>
val returnedVal = MutableLiveData<userentity>()
init {
    val getDao = UserRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application).userDao()
    repo = theRepository(getDao)
    alldata = repo.allUsers

}

fun findbyID(id: Int){
    viewModelScope.launch {
       returnedVal.value = repo.findbyID(id)
    }
}
```

}

**Fragment**

```
 override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    val usermodel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModel::class.java)
    usermodel.alldata.observe(this, Observer {
        Log.e(TAG,usermodel.alldata.value.toString())
    })
    usermodel.returnedVal.observe(this, Observer {
        tv1.text = usermodel.returnedVal.value.toString()
    })

    allData.setOnClickListener {
        tv1.text = usermodel.alldata.value.toString()
    }

    findByID.setOnClickListener {
        usermodel.findbyID(et2.text.toString().toInt())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

`LiveData` can be used to get value from `ViewModel` to `Fragment`.

Make the function `findbyID` return `LiveData` and observe it in the fragment.

Function in `ViewModel`

```
fun findbyID(id: Int): LiveData</*your data type*/> {
    val result = MutableLiveData</*your data type*/>()
    viewModelScope.launch {
       val returnedrepo = repo.delete(id)
       result.postValue(returnedrepo)
    }
    return result.
}
```

Observer in `Fragment`

```
findbyId.observer(viewLifeCycleOwner, Observer { returnedrepo ->
   /* logic to set the textview */
})
```

Comment: I've sorted the issue with the Nullpointerexception and I'm finally receiving the value back in the Fragment but I'm receiving same value three times, instead of one. Any thought how I can fix that?

Comment: Check if the value is being posted three times to the livedata...

Comment: Thanks Nataraj, your idea of using MutableLiveData for transferring the value to the UI was superb.I had to sort a few other things out, but I have finally manage to get one value back to the UI. I am going to post the answer in a minute. Thank you again!

Comment: For this code to work, I had to make my fragment implement LifecycleObserver.

Comment: Sorry, worked once but know, even with LifecycleObserver implemented on fragment, it is not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Another way without using LiveData would be like this,

Similar to `viewModelScope` there is also a `lifecycleScope` available with lifecycle-aware components, which can be used from the UI layer. Following is the example,

**Fragment**

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    findByID.setOnClickListener {
        lifecycleScope.launch{
            val res = usermodel.findbyID(et2.text.toString().toInt())
            // use returned value to do anything.
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
//1st option
// make the function suspendable itself.use aync instead of launch and then
// use await to collect the returned value.
suspend fun findbyID(id: Int): userEntity  {
    val job = viewModelScope.async {
       val returnedrepo = repo.delete(id)
       Log.e(TAG,returnedrepo.toString())
       return@async returnedrepo
    }
    return job.await()
}

//2nd option
// make the function suspendable itself. but switch the execution on IO
// thread.(since you are making a DB call)
suspend fun findbyID(id: Int): userEntity  {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
       val returnedrepo = repo.delete(id)
       Log.e(TAG,returnedrepo.toString())
       return@withContext returnedrepo
    }
}
```

Since LiveData is specific to Android Environment, Using Kotlin Flow becomes a better option in some places, which offers similar functionality.

Comment: Hm, disagree, using suspending functions in the ViewModels is not advisable since now the ViewModel might be accessed inside a totally different CoroutineScope which doesn't match the scope of the ViewModel. If you install the SonarLint code checker it also warns about this as a CodeSmell with severity "Major"

Comment: Well, that will depend on the case. Some cases may require the caller scope to be less than the ViewModel scope because the operation/data is only required as long as the caller is active. In some cases, where operation/data is required irrespective of the caller lifecycle, suspend function will not make sense, and ViewModel or any external scope(injected from outside) with a higher appropriate lifecycle should be used.
Moreover for single-shot requests suspend functions seem more suitable than LiveData or even Kotlin Flows which are better suited for a stream of data.